# Which are some good books to research spaced repetition and long term memory?

Tags: learning, memory, long-term-memory, study-cognitive-sciences, spaced-repetition

I am developing an application to help students remember what they learn.
But I need deeper and more grounded research in topics of:

1. Spaced repetition / Revision
2. Forgetting Curve
3. Long term memory
4. Memorization

Please suggest some good books / sources that cover most of these topics in a technical way (not kind of self help books). Or books that you think will be helpful to develop such a system.